# Laravel 5.6 Error on clicking the Patient list when creating a new doctor account

Tags: php, laravel-5

question 1.I have a thesis project about a certain clinic, I have a default users in my database, The default doctor doesn't have any problems or errors, but when i create a new doctor account, and when i click the patient list I get this error

```
Undefined variable: patient (View:C:\Users\patri\OneDrive\Desktop\Megason_noOTP\resources\views\patient-management\list.blade.php)

Please help TIA!!

    enter code here


public function index(){
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('usertype','usertype.permissions')->get();
    $permissions = [];
    foreach($user[0]->usertype->permissions as $permission)
    {
        array_push($permissions, $permission->name);
    }

    $patients = $this->getPatients();

    $data = array(
        'permissions' => $permissions,
        'patients' => $patients
    );

    return view('patient-management.list')->with('data',$data);

}

public function getPatients(){
    if(Auth::user()->type == 2){
        return PatientDetail::where('doctor_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('doctor.doctorDetails','user')->get();
    }else if(Auth::user()->type == 3){
        return PatientDetail::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('doctor.doctorDetails','user')->get();
    }
    else{
        return PatientDetail::with('doctor.doctorDetails','user')->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using patient in the blade template but from the controller, you sending as patients. can you please share your blade template. your error in blade not in controller.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXNBqLQX5IDJnREHYNdsgKf0FRj3GtCB/view?usp=sharing    you can download the code since i can't post it all here. TIA

Comment: when you are getting this error while deleting? or any specific action?

Comment: i'm getting this error when i create a new DOCTOR account. I have a default doctor account that doesn't have any errors but when i create a new doctor account and when i click the patient list, i get this error Undefined variable: patient (View:C:\Users\patri\OneDrive\Desktop\Megason_noOTP\resources\views\patient-management\list.blade.php)

Comment: i also get some errors may i delete all the patients

Comment: on delete button click you will get an error because you are using patient outside foreach

Comment: where should i put the foreach? where should i edit the delete button, on the list.blade or on the patient controller?